# Returning the index of an empty element inside an array

Tags: javascript

So I have an array let's say :

```
var arr = ['apples' , 'cherries' , 'strawberries']
```

and after so much coding, I get hungry so I eat the `'cherries'`
so now I have

```
arr = ['apples',null,'strawberries']
```

So I was wondering if there is some sort of JavaScript function that can return the first null element inside an array ?

Let's say for instance my grandma gives me `'potatoes'` and I want to add them inside the null space I have like a good boy I am, and I need the index of that null element so I may know where to place my sweet goods from grandma.

Comment: Is this a sort of problem taken from a course of javascript? Take a look to [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: No it is not. I want to push some data in firebase with specific indexes, (1 , 2 , 3 ,4 so on ) and If I delete an element it becomes null, and I want to put the new data inside there instead of putting it at the end of the array with some wierd id that firebase generates.

Comment: The real question is why would you eat the cherries when you have the option of delicious strawberries or the full tasty meal of a giant Honeycrisp apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [W3C documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp) :

```
arr.findIndex(element => element === null);
```

Replace :

```
arr[arr.findIndex(element => element === null)] = "potatoes";
```

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for :D Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try removing the element using below code :

```
var arr = ['apples' , 'cherries' , 'strawberries'];

arr.splice(1,1);
```

and remove and add try :

```
var arr = ['apples' , 'cherries' , 'strawberries'];

arr.splice(1,1, 'potatoes');
```

Comment: Yes, however I don't know the index of the null element so I cant splice on it :/

Answer (score 1):

Since `null` is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value you can simply use [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and match on falsy values:

```js
var arr = ['apples',null,'strawberries']

let index = arr.findIndex(x => !x)

console.log(index)
console.log(arr[index])
```